# Angular 1: check all check boxes in a large ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have an table created using ng-repeat and there hundreds of rows, up to 600 or 700. Each row includes a checkbox and I have a "Check All" box at the top to check all the boxes in one go. However I'm running into browser performance issues, IE11 (the clients preferred choice) in particular becomes unresponsive. After several minutes all the checkboxes appear checked but you still can't scroll or do anything so it is effectively useless.

I have created a controller array and when the checkAll box is clicked it loops through the model (the one used in ng-repeat) and adds a value to the array. I presume it's this looping through the array that is causing the slow-down but I'm not sure. Pagination has been ruled out, they want all the rows on one page.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Table Header</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAllCheckBox" ng-model="vm.allChecked" ng-change="vm.tickOrUntickAllCheckBoxes()" /> 
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="payment in vm.payments>
      <td>{{ payment.somePaymentValue }}</td>
      <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="paymentsApprovalCheckbox" 
              ng-checked="vm.approvedPayments.indexOf(payment.payId) > - 1"
              ng-value="payment.payId" ng-model="payment.approved" 
              ng-click="vm.handleCheckBoxClick(payment.payId)" /> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the angular function that checks/unchecks all

```
vm.tickOrUntickAllCheckBoxes = function(){
    if (vm.allChecked == false) {
        vm.approvedPayments = [];
    } else {    
        vm.payments.forEach(function(payment){
            vm.approvedPayments.push(payment.payId);
        });
    }
};
```

Swapping out the angular vm.tickOrUntickAllCheckBoxes() function for a plain old javascript option makes the checkAll box work almost instantaneously in IE11 however I lose access to the checked payment.payId values. I wonder is there away for angular to get them? Here is the plain javascript checkAll() function:

```
<script>
    function checkAll(x) {
        var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('paymentsApprovalCheckbox');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length ; i++) {
            checkBoxes[i].checked = (x.checked == true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then I update the checkAll checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAllCheckBox" ng-model="vm.allChecked" onclick="checkAll(this)" />
```

If you check one checkbox individually then the ng-model="payment.approved" in the repeating checkboxes is updated but this does not happen if they are checked with the checkAll function. Is it possible for angular to detect the boxes checked with checkAll()? I guess this is just putting off the same old inevitable slow-down to a slightly later point in the process.

Anyone have any ideas or work-arounds? Thanks!

Comment: That's one of the flaws of Angular 1. Because of the dirty checking mechanism, it will almost continuously run the `indexOf()` function, among hundreds of records, for each one of the hundreds of rows. That's dozens of thousands of operations for each repaint. Instead of running `indexOf()`, you should find a way to store a true-false value somewhere, that would be like caching the `indexOf()` result and run it only once.

Comment: I've solved large list performance issues with Angular 1 in the past using "virtual" lists. The idea is that only the visible items on the screen are rendered, which saves you from hundreds of unnecessary bindings which can cause a huge performance problem. Do a google search for "angular virtual scroll" and you will find a few options available.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the ng-model to the best of its abilities. In your controller:

```
$onInit() {
  // If you need this from a REST call to populate, you'll have to
  // remember to do that here;
  this.model = {
    all: true,
    items: {}
  };
}
```

In your loop:

```
<tr>
  <th>Table Header</th>
  <th>
    <input type="checkbox"
      id="checkAllCheckBox"
      ng-model="vm.model.all"
      ng-change="vm.tickOrUntickAllCheckBoxes()" /> 
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="payment in vm.payments track by $index">
  <td ng-bind="payment.somePaymentValue"></td>
  <td>
      <input type="checkbox"
        class="paymentsApprovalCheckbox" 
        ng-change="vm.approvedPayments($index)"
        ng-model="vm.model.items[$index]" /> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then in your controller:

```
tickOrUntickAllCheckBoxes() {
  const boxes = this.model.items.length;
  this.model.all = !this.model.all;
  // Several ways to do this, forEach, map, etc.,
  this.model.items.forEach((item) => { item.checked = !this.model.all });
}
```

And for setting it individually:

```
approvedPayments(idx) {
  // Sets all the item's boxes checked, or unchecked;
  this.model.items[idx].checked = !this.model.items[idx].checked;

  // Possible call to extended model to get payment info; 
  handleCheckBoxClick(idx);
}
```

You should be able to put all the payment information into the one approvedPayments() method rather than have two separate methods (move logic out of template and into the controller or a service). I.e., your model could look like:

```
this.model.items = [
  // One 'option' with id, payment etc;
  {
    id: 73,
    paymentId: 73,
    somePaymentValue: 210.73,
    currencyType: 'GBP',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    // Another 'option' etc...
  }
]
```

One issue to note is the incompatibility of [ngChecked with ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked), had to look it up (which is why I haven't used ng-checked in the above).

Answer (score 0):

Thank to everyone for the suggestions. The solution I came up with was to push some of the work back to the server side. Instead of just loading the payments model (in which each payment record contains a lot of info) i am now loading two additional models when the page loads, one of which is a set of key/value pairs where the keys are payId and the values are all false and another one with the same keys and all values are true. Example:

```
{
     "1": false,
     "2": false
}
```

These are used for the checkAll/Uncheck all - just set the vm.approvedIDs variable to the true or false one. Then, the vm.approvedIDs variable is used as the model in the ng-repeat checkbox.

I have to do a bit of extra work on the server side when the user sends the approvedIDs back to the server to get only the key/id of the 'true' entries. Here are the relevant angular controller functions:

```
$onInit() {
    // call http to get 'data' from server
    vm.payments = data.payments;
    vm.paymentIDsFalse = vm.approvedIDs = data.paymentIDsFalse;
    vm.paymentIDsTrue = data.paymentIDsTrue;
};

// tick/untick all boxes
vm.tickOrUntickAllCheckBoxes = function(){
    if (vm.allChecked == false) {
        vm.approvedPayments = vm.paymentIDsFalse;
    } else {
        vm.approvedPayments = vm.paymentIDsTrue;
    }
};

// tick/untick one box
vm.handleCheckBoxClick = function(payId, currentValue){
    vm.approvedPayments[payId] = currentValue;
};

vm.submitApprovedIds = function(){
    // post vm.approvedPayments to server 
};
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Table Header</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAllCheckBox" ng-model="vm.allChecked" ng-change="vm.tickOrUntickAllCheckBoxes()"  /> 
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="payment in vm.payments>
            <td>{{ payment.somePaymentValue }}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="paymentsApprovalCheckbox"
                    ng-value="payment.payId"
                    ng-model="vm.approvedPayments[payment.payId]"
                    ng-click="vm.handleCheckBoxClick(payment.payId, vm.approvedPayments[payment.payId])" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It looks to me as if there must be a better way than creating these additional models but it is working pretty smoothly for now and I can move on to the next thing!